# NullPointerException when I try to executeQuery

Tags: java

I got this Exception, but I really don't understand why. I found same problem but there was not initialized request.

```
import java.sql.*;

class Database {
public static Connection connection;
public static Statement request;
public static ResultSet result;
...
result = request.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts;");

}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does the field `request` contain null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error occurs when the object that is trying to execute the method (in this case request trying to executeQuery) is null. 
Therefore, be sure that in your code you include at some point:

```
request = connection.createStatement();
```

Also make sure that you have assigned something to connection, for example by using DriverManager.getConnection.

Documentation for the getConnection() method can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties)).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I forgot that my createStatement was in another method which I didn't call in main program because I needn't it in this case.